# Put file contents as PDF comment (respecting UTF-8)

Tags: unicode, filesystem-access, pdfcomment, catchfile

I want to have file contents rendered as comment in a PDF file. I decided for [pdfcomment](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment), which works. `pdfcomment` requires newlines being typeset as `\textCR\textLF`. Which leas me to the following setting:

I would like to read the contents of a file, replace a newline by `\textCR\textLF` and have this passed to pdfcomment. As additional challenge, character sequences such as `{`, `\_`, .. need to be preserved.

### Rough example:

`demo.bib`:

```
@article{demo,
  author = {Demo Frühling},
  comment = {Fr\"{u}hling}
}
```

After reading the file, following text should be passed to pdfcomment:

```
@article{demo,\textCR\textLF
  author = {Demo Frühling},\textCR\textLF
  comment = {Fr\"{u}hling}\textCR\textLF
}\textCR\textLF
```

Longer desired result:

```
\pdfcomment[icon=Help]{
@article{demo,\textCR\textLF
  author = {Demo Frühling},\textCR\textLF
  comment = {Fr\"{u}hling}\textCR\textLF
}\textCR\textLF}
```

### Example with (non-working) code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\newread\reader

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
@article{demo,
  author = {Demo Frühling},
  comment = {Fr\"{u}hling}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\pdfcomment[icon=Help]{
\makeatletter
\advance\endlinechar \@M
\openin%
\reader=demo.bib%
\relax
\loop
    \read\reader to \x
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \x \textCR\textLF
\repeat
\closein\reader
\advance\endlinechar -\@M
\makeatother
}

\end{document}
```

That renders to following:

[image: help icon with wrong text]

This is not the thing, I intended. The comment should have the full text of the file.

### Solution Thoughts

- I played around with [catchfile](https://ctan.org/pkg/catchfile?lang=de), but with no success. (Related question:  [\CatchFileDef vs ( \input or \@@input )](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48729/9075))
- I think [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) with `\DTLforeach` could work somehow, but I don't how to read a non-CSV file with data tool
- [readarray](https://ctan.org/pkg/readarray) looks good with `readrecordarray`, but I don't know how to craft a `for` loop, especially the end condition is unclear to me. Related answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116901/9075

Answer (score 2):

Actually easy - i am just not sure if one can easily include the linebreaks, but i am sure you are going to find out. Using expl3 because it's much more readable in there ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}
    
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
    @article{demo,
        author = {demo}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\file_get:nnN {demo.bib} {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \_ 
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \$
    \char_set_catcode_other:N \{
    \char_set_catcode_other:N\}
} \l_tmpa_tl
    
\exp_args:NnV \use:n {\pdfcomment[icon=Help]}{\l_tmpa_tl}
    
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

And just in case you don't want to change all characters to other manually you could also iterate over a squence and read the file as a string:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}
    
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
    @article{demo,
        author = {demo}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \l_tmpa_ior
\ior_open:Nn \l_tmpa_ior {demo.bib}
\seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
\ior_str_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_ior {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
} 

\exp_args:Nnx \use:n {\pdfcomment[icon=Help]}{\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\textLF}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab` to be completely safe. (ah, I have a question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/647304/250119 on how to read whole file and some additional performance discussion)